# nginx appears to use rewrite regardless of server_name

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following config file.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name web.example.com;

  access_log  /var/www/example/shared/log/web.access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/example/shared/log/web.error.log debug;

  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.net$request_uri; permanent;
}
```

When I make a request for curl -Ii -H "Host: example.com" http://example.com the above rewrite rule works. (ARGH)..

The server_name explicitly says "web.example.com"

2014/11/18 22:49:20 [notice] 30694#0: *1868 "^/(.*)$" matches "/", client: 1.2.3.4, server: web.example.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2014/11/18 22:49:20 [notice] 30694#0: *1868 rewritten redirect: "http://www.example.net/", client: 1.2.3.4, server: web.example.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

Not present here is the other server { } configs.  Xavier (below) pointed out that I had set default_server for listen: 443; but not for listen: 80.  (argh)

Comment: Read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the strict solution to the issue.

What's happening is that you have only one server block and it becomes the default server block for all requests, even the ones not matching the server name. You simply need to add a default server block in your configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
}
```

By the way, you have a typo (semicolon before `permanent`) and you don't need a rewrite as you have specific regular expression. Use this instead :

`return 301 http://www.example.net$request_uri;`

Comment: I do have multiple server blocks and one with a default_server.  I didn't want to display my entire config file. :)

Comment: I tried that, just have a return 301 http://www.example.net$request_uri;  I suspect, it also needs a location / { return ... }.  I don't want to try it right now, let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you need to show your full configuration files because I *never* saw such a behaviour before in all version and OS I used nginx on.

Comment: I've created gist here: https://gist.github.com/danlo/88973cafb2898c0bd017  I have cut out all the mod_pagespeed (brevity) and ssl information (paranoia)  I will delete it in a day or so.

Comment: @Daniel You don't have a default server explicitely declared for port 80, only for port 443. So as I said in my answer the server block from your post is implicitely being used as the default server for every Host header not matching `web.example.com` or `*.example.com` (it's the case for `example.com`) because it's the first seen in the configuration and listening on `*:80`.

Comment: Drat, adding that in!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After a while...

I found that I needed the location / { } wrapped around it

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web.example.com;

    access_log  /var/www/example/shared/log/web.access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/example/shared/log/web.error.log debug;

    location / {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.net$request_uri permanent;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's not the strict solution to the original post. What's happening is that you have only one server block and it becomes the default server block for all requests, even the ones not matching the server name. You simply need to add `server { listen 80 default_server; }` in your configuration. Btw you have a typo (semicolon before `permanent`) and you don't need a rewrite (no regex) but a return `return 301 http://www.example.net$request_uri;`, it will even be more effective.